# d3/topojson Cannot get centroid of path element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have a USA JSON file that I'm using to generate a map.  The paths are generating states just fine, but now I'd like to add the state name at the center of each path/state.

Here's an example of JSON file

```
var usa = {"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME": "Alabama"}, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -88.124658, 30.283640 ]...
```

I've created States by appending to the SVG I've already created

```
var allStates = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(usa.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
```

And here is where I'm trying to add the state names as text

```
var allStatesNames = svg.selectAll('text')
  .data(usa.features)
  .enter().append("svg:text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + path.centroid(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
  .text(function(d) {return d.properties.NAME})
```

But I just keep getting this back

```
<text transform="translate(NaN,NaN)">Virginia</text>
```

Why am I getting NaN and what should I be using instead?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that path.centroid needs both the type of the shape as well as the coordinates, so you can't just pass in the coordinates. You can actually just pass in the entire feature with d.

Try putting path.centroid(d) in the return of your transform attr and it should work for you. It seems that path.centroid(d.geometry) works as well, but is less correct.

Comment: `path.centroid()` takes a feature actually, so you would need to do `path.centroid(d)`.

Comment: So it does -- looks like they both work. Thanks for the heads-up!